# JposException: Can't connect printer device (issue on linux only)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javapos, posprinter

I've developed a java application that works perfectly on windows when i print a receipt.
The issue comes when the same java application is tested it in Ubuntu 14.04, and gives me this:

```
jpos.JposException: Can't connect printer device=SRP-350II
    at com.bixolon.jpos.services.printers.PrinterBaseService.claim(PrinterBaseService.java:256)
    at jpos.BaseJposControl.claim(BaseJposControl.java:296)
    at PruebaPOSImpresion.main(PruebaPOSImpresion.java:36)
```

It seems that the app finds the printer declared in jpos.xml since does the "open", but not the "claim".
And it's strange that when i execute the "check health" on the printer (with the printer utility) it can print the test page with no problem.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I am having the exactly same problem.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: You must give permissions to / dev / bus / usb /, with that the problem is solved in our case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give permissions to /dev/bus/usb/, so the jpos connection will recognize the connected printer

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer this solution
[Java POS printer error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164525/java-pos-printer-error)

Check your Jpos.xml path directory.. Windows vs Ubuntu
[File paths in Java (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722730/file-paths-in-java-linux)